# Open subschemes of integral schemes determined by image in stalk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is an integral scheme with generic point $\eta$, and $U \subset X$ is an open subscheme. If the restriction $\mathcal O_X(X) \to \mathcal O_X(U)$ is an isomorphism, do we necessarily have $U = X$? I believe this is true (I have an argument for the affine case) but I don't know how to approach the general case.

(The title of the question explains the motivation: the condition is equivalent to the injections $\mathcal O_X(X) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_{X, \eta}$ and $\mathcal O_X(U) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_{X, \eta}$ having the same image.)

Comment: $X=\mathbb{A}^2$, $U=\mathbb{A}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ should give a counterexample.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is moreover Noetherian and normal and $F \subset X$ has codimension at least $2$, then $O(X) \rightarrow O(X \backslash F)$ should be an isomorphism as well: indeed, a rational function on the spectrum of a normal Noetherian domain is regular iff it is regular at every prime ideal of height $1$, see Stacks 10.157.6.

Comment: Oops!

Hmm, is it at least true that each *point* of an integral scheme is determined by the image of its stalk in the generic stalk?

Comment: I’m not sure (these pathological examples still feel a but mysterious to me), but I’d say no in general – because of things like the line with two origins.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping my previous comments (and then some) in an answer:

By Stacks 10.157.6, if $R$ is a normal Noetherian domain, $R=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}}{R_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ runs through prime ideals of height one.

It follows that if $X$ is a normal integral Noetherian scheme, then for any closed subset $F\subset X$ with codimension at least $2$, $O(X) \rightarrow O(X \backslash F)$ is an isomorphism.

So open subsets are not determined by their ring of regular functions (as seen in the fraction field). But maybe *points* are determined by the image of their ring of stalks in the field of rational functions ?

Short answer: no.

Consider the line with two origins (glue two copies of $\mathbb{A}_1$ along $\mathbb{A}_1 \backslash \{0\}$): then the two origins (the zero in each copy) have, in the field of rational functions, the same ring of stalks. This is because $x=y$ in the field of rational functions ($x$ being the coordinate on the first copy of $\mathbb{A}^1$, $y$ the coordinate in the second copy).

Longer answer: actually, it’s *yes* for reasonable schemes.

**Claim**: let $X$ be a *separated* integral scheme, $x,y \in X$. If $O_{X,x}$ and $O_{Y,y}$ have the same image in $K(X)$, then $x=y$.

*Proof*: let $R$ be the image of $O_{X,x}$ in $K(X)$: it’s a local domain with fraction field $K(X)$. We have two maps $u,v: \mathrm{Spec}{R} \rightarrow X$ given by $\mathrm{Spec}{R} \cong \mathrm{Spec}O_{X,x} \rightarrow X$ (and same for $O_{Y,y}$).

There is a closed subscheme $Z$ of $\mathrm{Spec}{R}$ such that a morphism $t: S \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}{R}$ factors through $Z$ iff $u \circ t=v \circ t$. Informally, $Z=\{z| u(z)=v(z)\}$; formally, $Z$ is the base change of the diagonal $X \rightarrow X \times_{\mathbb{Z}} X$ (a closed immersion as $X$ is separated) by $(u,v): \mathrm{Spec}{R} \rightarrow X\times_{\mathbb{Z}} X$.

The hypothesis means that the two morphisms $u \circ \eta$ and $v\circ \eta$ are equal, where $\eta$ is the map induced by the inclusion of $R$ in $K(X)$. So $Z$ contains the generic point of $\mathrm{Spec}{R}$. As $Z$ is a closed subscheme, $Z \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}{R}$ is a surjective closed immersion, hence, as $R$ is reduced, an isomorphism, and $u=v$. Therefore, if $p \in \mathrm{Spec}{R}$ is the closed point, $x=u(p)=v(p)=y$.